# Why are uploads maxing out CPU?

Tags: email, cpu, osx-lion, ftp

Some odd behaviour ... when sending / uploading files, my CPU usage goes to about 100%; Activity Monitor reports 'Kernel Task' as the culprit. I first noticed this when sending emails in Mail, but it is also happening whenever I use *any* upload protocol:

- Email attachment;
- FTP using Cyberduck or FireFTP (within Firefox);
- Syncing Evernote (suspect this is also FTP?);
- FTP via command line (`ftp -u`)

Any idea why this happens, or how to stop it?

(OSX Lion 10.7.2, Macbook Pro 2.4 Core Duo; customisations include Growl and Quicksilver)

**Update**: first line of output from `top -o cpu`:

```
PID    COMMAND      %CPU  TIME     #TH  #WQ  #PORT #MREG
0      kernel_task  122.3 20:13.81 73/4 0    2     1907
```

**Update 2**: Just decided to try this out using wifi instead of my USB 3G modem ... and the problem disappears! Five samples during ftp upload give:

```
$ top -l 5 -stats pid,command,cpu,th | grep kernel_task
0      kernel_task      0.0  71/2
0      kernel_task      2.2  71/3
0      kernel_task      2.1  71/2
0      kernel_task      2.1  71/2
0      kernel_task      2.2  71/2
```

So the issue seems to be any upload with the USB modem ... but would still be good to find a solution!

Comment: Do you have an antivirus running ?

Comment: @Shadok ... no antivirus! Also tried this after quitting Quicksilver (thinking catalog updates might be happening during uploads), no effect.

Comment: Ok, could you try opening a terminal and running 'top' before provoking the problem and pasting the display of the top command when the cpu is bound ? We'll see what's eating the CPU, it should help targeting the problem.

Comment: Hmm... it might related to I/O because I have hard time believing the ftp command would consume such amount of kernel time. Just out of curiosity what is your max bandwith during ftp transfers ?

Comment: Bandwidth goes up to 400 kilobit (USB modem) max, typically half that. Just checked with Mail attachment again (SMTP) and it's the same kernel_task process!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, let's continue here...

It might related to I/O because I have hard time believing the ftp command would consume such amount of kernel time.
A big network transfer rate could be responsible for that though but you should be sending few dozens Mo/s before you hit 100% of CPU on a CPU like this.

Have a look [here](http://reviews.cnet.com/8301-13727_7-10330458-263.html) for a list of things causing kernel_task to go mad and report if you have any luck with it :)

Comment: No luck on that link but see my update 2 above ...